# Replace HTML String

Tags: html, css, uiwebview

Currently i am working in a project in which i am using webView. The Project is in **Swift 4.** I am getting HTML string from web-service. The HTML String contains text as well as images. So i want to change font size of text, background color as well as change the image size from whole html string, suppose if font size comes 10 times so i want to change font for all. I am sharing HTML string as well as its output.

```html
<p class=\"MsoNormal\" style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt'> </p><div align=\"center\"><table class=\"MsoTableGrid\" border=\"1\" cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" style='border-collapse:collapse;border:none'>  <tr style='height:12.5pt'>   <td width=\"216\" valign=\"top\" style='width:2.25in;border:solid #4BACC6 1.0pt;   background:#DAEEF3;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:12.5pt'>   <p class=\"MsoNormal\" style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:   normal'><b>Forward path</b></p>   </td>   <td width=\"240\" valign=\"top\" style='width:2.5in;border:solid #4BACC6 1.0pt;   border-left:none;background:#DAEEF3;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:12.5pt'>   <p class=\"MsoNormal\" style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:   normal'><b>Single loops</b></p>   </td>  </tr>  <tr style='height:12.5pt'>   <td width=\"216\" valign=\"top\" style='width:2.25in;border:solid #4BACC6 1.0pt;   border-top:none;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:12.5pt'>   <p class=\"MsoNormal\" style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:   normal'><b><span style='position:relative;top:6.0pt'><img src='data:image/.png;base64,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' /></span></b></p>   </td>   <td width=\"240\" valign=\"top\" style='width:2.5in;border-top:none;border-left:none;   border-bottom:solid #4BACC6 1.0pt;border-right:solid #4BACC6 1.0pt;   padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:12.5pt'>   <p class=\"MsoNormal\" style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:   normal'><span style='position:relative;top:6.0pt'><img src='data:image/.png;base64,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' /></span>,<span style='position:relative;   top:6.0pt'> </span><span style='position:relative;top:6.0pt'><img src='data:image/.png;base64,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' /></span></p>   </td>  </tr>  <tr style='height:17.75pt'>   <td width=\"216\" valign=\"top\" style='width:2.25in;border:solid #4BACC6 1.0pt;   border-top:none;background:#DAEEF3;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:17.75pt'>   <p class=\"MsoNormal\" style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:   normal'><b>Associated path factor</b></p>   </td>   <td width=\"240\" valign=\"top\" style='width:2.5in;border-top:none;border-left:none;   border-bottom:solid #4BACC6 1.0pt;border-right:solid #4BACC6 1.0pt;   background:#DAEEF3;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:17.75pt'>   <p class=\"MsoNormal\" style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:   normal'><b>Determinant of graph</b></p>   </td>  </tr>  <tr style='height:17.75pt'>   <td width=\"216\" valign=\"top\" style='width:2.25in;border:solid #4BACC6 1.0pt;   border-top:none;padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:17.75pt'>   <p class=\"MsoNormal\" style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:   normal'><b><span style='position:relative;top:6.0pt'><img src='data:image/.png;base64,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' /></span></b></p>   </td>   <td width=\"240\" valign=\"top\" style='width:2.5in;border-top:none;border-left:none;   border-bottom:solid #4BACC6 1.0pt;border-right:solid #4BACC6 1.0pt;   padding:0in 5.4pt 0in 5.4pt;height:17.75pt'>   <p class=\"MsoNormal\" style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;line-height:   normal'><b><span style='position:relative;top:7.0pt'><img src='data:image/.png;base64,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' /></span></b></p>   </td>  </tr> </table></div><p class=\"MsoNormal\" style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt'><span style='font-size:5.0pt;line-height:115%'>&nbsp;</span></p><p class=\"MsoNormal\" style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;background: #DAEEF3'><b>&nbsp;</b>Transfer function is given by,</p><p class=\"MsoNormal\" style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;background: #DAEEF3'>&nbsp;<b><span style='position:relative;top:15.0pt'><img src='data:image/.png;base64,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' /></span></b></p><p class=\"MsoNormal\" style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt'><table cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" align=\"left\">  <tr>   <td width=\"28\" height=\"8\"></td>  </tr>  <tr>   <td></td>   <td><img src='data:image/.png;base64,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' /></td>  </tr> </table><b>&nbsp;</b></p><br clear=\"ALL\"><p class=\"MsoNormal\" style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt'>&nbsp;</p><p class=\"MsoNormal\" style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;background: #DAEEF3'>Self loop at the input node is invalid.</p><p class=\"MsoNormal\" style='margin-bottom:0in;margin-bottom:.0001pt;background: #DAEEF3'><b><span style='color:blue'>&nbsp;</span></b><span style='color:black'>Hence, the correct option is (A).</span></p>
```

here you can see that there is background color and font size is different. somewhere were its bold and somewhere its regular, And also there is a so many space between image and text

[image: here you can see that there is background color and font size is different. somewhere were its bold and somewhere its regular, And also there is a so many space between image and text]

Comment: That's what css is for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally got the solution. no need to replace font-size or image size. do write below HTML and pass your HTML in between. while load this into the webview Your font size will be normal and image as well. [You can find image that i have implemented in my app.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLdGf.png)

```
let aData = "your HTML string from web API"

"<html><head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0\"><style type=\"text/css\">span{top:0 !important;}img{max-width: 100%; width:auto; height: auto; zoom: \(aZoom); vertical-align:middle !important}body{color: #000}iframe{ min-width: 100%; width: 100px; *width: 100%;}</iframe></style></head><body>\(aData)</body></html>"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change top:15.0pt to 4.0pt, all top:6.0pt to 2.0pt, and change background:#DAEEF3; to whatever you like in the HTML file.

To change image size, just provide height and width of the image at the end of the img tag.